# How to Send Status Updates to the User during Partial Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have the following:

1. Master Page
2. StatusDisplay - Ascx user control that shows MS AJAX Exceptions on PartialPostback or Update Happenning during beginRequest to endRequest
3. Pages with Multiple levels of .ascx Web user controls, some loaded dynamically

Currently, when postback happens in Update Panel, the StatusDisplay shows "updating requests .. " and exceptions if any at the end.

I also want to send out specific status updates, like "Customer added" from different places that this StatusDisplay should show. Currently, there is no knowledge of the presence of the StatusDisplay in other controls and I want to keep it that way.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a technique called reverse ajax. Reverse Ajax allows servers to push content out to browsers immediately as it becomes available, which is usually implemented by a combo of a IFrame, Response flushing, and a common javascript function to handle the callbacks

[easy incremental status updates for long requests](http://encosia.com/2007/10/03/easy-incremental-status-updates-for-long-requests/) is a great article on the subject.

The sample implementation here relys on the pretence that the javascript its creating and flushing to the client has a javascript callback function "UpdateProgress" already attached to the parent window object (as the call was made within an IFrame). As the task is long running the code executes flushes to the client and executes the javascript function performing whatever.

```
protected void UpdateProgress(int PercentComplete, string Message)
{
  // Write out the parent script callback.
  Response.Write(String.Format(
    "<script>parent.UpdateProgress({0}, '{1}');</script>", 
    PercentComplete, Message));
  // To be sure the response isn't buffered on the server.
  Response.Flush();
}
```

Comment: goodlink, but can't understand how it will work with postback scenarios.

Comment: you could use the idea of using a client side function that updates the status when postback is complete ie render out a script tag that updates the status message, ( this could be abstracted to a base class that each control uses, or you could use eventing if you wanted )